# performSegue(withIdentifier) fails in one instance of viewController

Tags: swift, swift3

I have a viewController to handle authenticating the user to an oAuth API. If there is a stored token in user.defaults this block runs

```
FRDStravaClient.sharedInstance().fetchCurrentAthlete(success: { (StravaAthlete) -> Void in
    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "AuthorizeSuccessfulSegue", sender: StravaAthlete.self)
}, failure: { (Error) in
    //some failure stuff
})
```

The segue is triggered and the user moves on to the rest of the app.

However, if the user needs to log in when they are returned to the app after authorizing it this block runs:

```
FRDStravaClient.sharedInstance().exchangeToken(forCode: code,
success: { (response: StravaAccessTokenResponse? ) in
    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "AuthorizeSuccessfulSegue", sender: response?.athlete)
}, failure:{ (error) -> Void in
    self.showAuthFailedWithError(error: (error?.localizedDescription)!)
    print(error!)
})
```

Which crashes the app with the error: 'Receiver () has no segue with identifier 'AuthorizeSuccessfulSegue''

Both success blocks use the same identifier which is correctly set in Interface Builder. self is referencing AuthViewController. Why is one working and the other is crashing?

Comment: Have you tried just making the sender `self`? Also if that's an asynchronous request, you should be performing the segue in an dispatch block like `DispatchQueue.main.async { self.performSegue... }`

Comment: This looks Okay to me. You sure these two blocks are in the same view controller?

Comment: @Pierce I had tried several variations on the sender as well as putting in the `DispatchQueue.main.async`  before posting but it didn't change anything (and I've tried it again, too) Both are async functions.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that the first function happens inside `viewDidLoad` while the second happens in a function of the VC called by appDelegate when you return from Safari and authorizing the app. I was instantiating a new AutViewController rather than getting the current instance.